# how to multiply each row of a matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am new on machine learning.Using python, numpy.
I need to get a dot product on a matrix with size (3, 2) and each row of a matrix with size (100, 2), which is

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
b = [[5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], ...] # it has 100 row
```

and what i want is:

```
np.dot(a, b[0])
np.dot(a, b[1])
```

i currently have:

```
z = np.dot(a, b)
```

but the dimension doesn't match

but i cannot use loop and the code need to be vectorized.

can anyone give me some hints, thank you so much!!

Comment: `np.dot(a,b.T)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a dot product to work, it requires the first dimension of `b` to match the second dimension of `a`. Thus you need to transpose `b`:

```
np.dot(a, b.T)
```

Output:

```
array([[15, 18, 21, 24],
       [35, 42, 49, 56],
       [55, 66, 77, 88]])
```

Or `a`, depending on the expected output:

```
>>> np.dot(b, a.T)
array([[15, 35, 55],
       [18, 42, 66],
       [21, 49, 77],
       [24, 56, 88]])
```

Comment: you mean **second** dimension of `a`

Comment: @nadapez yes it's already fixed ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! just one more question, how to do addition to each row of matrix with a vextor?

Comment: Simply `matrix + vector` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to compute the dot product of the matrix of shape `3,2` with the **transpose** of the matrix of shape `100,2`

You can get the transpose of a matrix `m` with `m.T`

So what you want is:

```
np.dot(a, b.T)
```

That will give you a matrix of shape `3,100` where each column is `np.dot(a,b[i])` for `i = 0,...,99`